# Matplotlib. How to change the line along bar perimeter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted `plt.bar` as shown below.[image]
But due to big density of bars some parts of plot is repainted to black color because each bar has black line along the perimeter of self.

How to change the color of this perimeter line?

Comment: In bar plot use argument `edgecolor = 'none'` or `edgecolor='k'`.

Comment: use of `edgecolor` is documented here: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar